# How to save webpage/image

Tags: c#, axwebbrowser

I am using the following project due to its ability to fill forms and click buttons programmatically:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5452/Microsoft-Web-Browser-Automation-using-C

I can browse internet programmatically however I am unable to save web pages. For example I tried to save images on my domain. I open the image however I can't save it programmatically:

```
private AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser axWebBrowser1;
object loc = "http://www.mydomain.com/img/logo.jpg";
object null_obj_str = "";
System.Object null_obj = 0;
this.axWebBrowser1.Navigate2(ref loc , ref null_obj, ref null_obj, ref null_obj_str, ref null_obj_str);

// I want to save jpg here...
HTMLDocument myDoc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
myDoc = (HTMLDocument) axWebBrowser1.Document;
// ...but don't know how to do it
```

There is a screenshot ability but I don't want to use that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show the source code... what have you tried (for saving the image) ? what is not working ?

Comment: Show some code what are you doing?

Comment: Hi Have look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110246/how-do-i-programatically-save-an-image-from-a-url

Comment: Yes, this one works :) but I can't manage to login programatically using WebClient. The user should retrieve images after login from my site.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="address."/>`

you can search "img"
after that is "src"

you can get address of file...