# Get Image from remote URL and upload to SharePoint 2010

Tags: upload, sharepoint-2010

I have some code that I've used to upload images to SharePoint and it works fine. I now need to expand this code and get an image from a remote URL... I've tried several things but I don't know what I need to do to get the file so I can upload it to a library.

Any help is appreciated.

current code:

```
 string filePath = @"C:\Users\username\Desktop\logo.jpg";
        string siteURL = "http://mydevsite.com/";
        string libraryName = "SOI_Images";

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteURL))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", filePath);

                SPFolder libFolder = oWeb.Folders[libraryName];

                // Prepare to upload 
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

                //Check the existing File out if the Library Requires CheckOut
                if (libFolder.RequiresCheckout)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SPFile fileOld = libFolder.Files[fileName];
                        fileOld.CheckOut();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

                // Upload document 
                SPFile spfile = libFolder.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, true);

                // Commit  
                //myLibrary.Update();

                //Check the File in and Publish a Major Version
                if (libFolder.RequiresCheckout)
                {
                    spfile.CheckIn("Upload Comment", SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                    spfile.Publish("Publish Comment");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked like a charm

```
        public static void MyUploadtoSharepoint(string _site, string _ListName, string _ImageURL, string _dateTaken, string _uid, string _userEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSite site = new SPSite(_site);
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            // SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList pics = web.Lists[_ListName];

            //use WebRequest to create stream
            WebRequest reqImg = WebRequest.Create(_ImageURL);

            //reqImg.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            WebResponse imgResponse = reqImg.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(imgResponse.GetResponseStream());

            Hashtable metaData = new Hashtable();
            metaData.Add("UserName", _uid);
            metaData.Add("DateTaken", _dateTaken);
            metaData.Add("userEmail", _userEmail);

            using (Image imgOriginal = Image.FromStream(reader.BaseStream, true))
            {
                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
                imgOriginal.Save(mstream, imgOriginal.RawFormat);

                MemoryStream msNew = null;
                using (msNew = new MemoryStream(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, mstream.GetBuffer().Length))
                {
                    msNew.Write(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, mstream.GetBuffer().Length);

                    var files = pics.RootFolder.Files.Add(_uid + ".png", msNew.ToArray(), metaData, true);

                    files.Item.SystemUpdate(false);
                    // files.CheckIn("");
                }
            }
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            site.Dispose();
            web.Dispose();
            imgResponse.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an HttpWebRequest to get the image and then save the resulting stream.
Here is another answer on that topic and a quick snippet.

[How do I programmatically save an image from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110246/how-do-i-programatically-save-an-image-from-a-url)

```
 string imageUrl = @"http://www.somedomain.com/image.jpg";
 using( HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl))
 using(WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse())
 using(Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream())
 {
    //save your file to the document library here.
 }//close stream, webResponse and HttpWebRequest
```